# If $f:(A, d_A)\longrightarrow (Y, d^{'})$ and $g:(B, d_B)\longrightarrow (Y, d^{'})$ are uniformly continuous then $h$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ and $(Y, d^{'})$ be metric spaces, $A, B\subset X$ subspaces such that $X=A\cup B$. Suppose $$f:(A, d_A)\longrightarrow (Y, d^{'})\quad \textrm{and}\quad g:(B, d_B)\longrightarrow (Y, d^{'}),$$ are both uniformly continuous such that $f|_{A\cap B}=g|_{A\cap B}$. Is it true that $h:(X, d)\longrightarrow (Y, d^{'})$ given by $$h(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccl} 
f(x)&\textrm{se}&x\in A\\ g(x)&\textrm{se}&x\in B\end{array}\right.$$ is also uniformly continuous?

What about the case $B=X\setminus A$ with $A$ compact?  **Finally, what if I suppose $h$ is continuous?**

**Notation:** $d_A$ and $d_B$ are the restriction of the metric $d$ to the subspaces $A$ and $B$, respectively.

**Obs:** Maybe additional hypothesis will be needed.

Comment: What progress have you made yourself?

Comment: We must show $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0; x, y\in X, d(x, y)<\delta\Rightarrow d^{'}(f(x), f(y))<\varepsilon$. This is clear if $x, y\in A$ or $x, y\in B$. The problem is when $x\in A$ and $y\in B$..

Comment: Is it assumed that $X$ is connected? If not, then $h$ need not be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Well, indeed that was a conjecture.. maybe that was the reason I wasn't able to show it yet..

Comment: @Tom how will the connectedness be used?

Comment: @PtF If $X$ is not connected, then it is possible that $A \cap B = \varnothing$, so there is no nice "overlap" between $f$ and $g$, although all the hypotheses will be satisfied.

Comment: How would lack of connectedness interfere with uniform continuity?

Comment: @copper.hat Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Without connectedness we have the following counter example. Let $A = (-\infty,0)$ and $B = (0,\infty)$. Let $f : A \to \Bbb{R}$ and $g : B \to \Bbb{R}$ be given by $f \equiv 0$ and $g \equiv 1$. Then $X = A\cup B = \Bbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ and 
$$
h(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
1 & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
which is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Nice man =) Well, you have showed it doesn't work without connectedness, but will it work only with connectedness of $X$?

Answer (score 2):

The function $h$ is not necessarily even continuous.

Let $X=\mathbb{R}, A=\mathbb{Q}, B= \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Define $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in A$, $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in B$.

Then both $f,g$ are uniformly continuous on $A,B$ respectively, but the function $h$ is not even continuous.

**Note**: By taking $A=[0,1], B = \mathbb{R} \setminus A$ we obtain the same result, even though $A$ is compact.

Comment: Do you want to make $g(x) = 0$?

Comment: @Tom: Yes indeed, thanks. Haven't had my morning cuppa yet :-).

Answer (score 1):

**Counterexample for the problem as written:**

$A = (0,1)$, $B = (1,2)$.  Take
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x \in A\\
1 & x \in B
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $A \cup B$.

This will work, however, in the case that both $A$ and $B$ are compact.

**Proof given compactness:**

We know the following: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in A$, we have $d(x,y) < \delta_1 \implies d'(h(x),h(y)) < \epsilon$ **and** for all $x,y \in B$, we have $d(x,y) < \delta_1 \implies d'(h(x),h(y)) < \epsilon$.

In order to have uniform continuity, we must find a $\delta$ that works when $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.

Suppose that $d(A,B) > 0$, then $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,d(A,B)\}$ works.

Otherwise, $d(A,B) = 0$, and so by compactness $A \cap B$ is non-empty.  Then $f$ is continuous on $A \cup B$ (which is compact) by the pasting lemma, and so it is uniformly continuous.

I am not sure whether the conditions can be relaxed further.  Perhaps $A$ and $B$ need only be closed?